# Reduced printing functionality in SSRS BIDS 2008 R2 "Preview" tab or bug?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, bids

**Problem:**
Printing from within BIDS 2008 R2 "Preview" tab hangs and must have the process ended in task manager.

Facts

- I can set the report as StartItem
  under Debug Configuration Properties
  for the project and then run,
  producing the Preview window.  And
  then successfully print.
- I can deploy the report to the
  Reporting Services server and
  successfully print from the Report
  Manager.
- I can create a new report with NO data source, simply placing text and images on the page and successfully print from within the Preview tab.
- Problem does NOT EXIST when using BIDS 2005, able to print from Preview Tab just fine
- I can export to any format from within Preview Tab (PDF for instance,) open the file and print successfully

**Troubleshooting Steps Taken (with same failed results):**

- Tried other SSRS projects
- Tried other SSRS reports
- Tried a new SSRS project, bare bones data access... no images, non-standard fonts, etc.
- Duplicated problem on different system (servers, workstations, new report, etc.)
- Used Jet 4.0 OLEDB connected to Access database as datasource
- Used SQL Server 2005 as datasource
- Used SQL Server 2008 as datasource
- Set NOCOUNT ON , on the SQL Server (various forum trolling suggestion)
- Set NOCOUNT OFF , on the SQL Server
- Changed printers (models, drivers, etc.)
- Tried a local printer connected via cable

**Question:**
Can anyone duplicate this behavior?  Is this a bug in BIDS 2008 R2 or was the development environment never intended to provide this more "production-like" functionality of printing from within the Preview Tab?

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: Anyone have thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having the same problem. The only additional info I can provide is that this issue occurs on systems running Windows XP SP3 as well as Windows 7 64-bit.
Also, if I click on the Print Layout icon when in Preview and then click on the print icon, everything works as expected.

I'm using BIDS 2008 R2 CU3.

11/2/2010: Response from Microsoft to a support ticket I put in yesterday:
Looks like you have found a bug. I was able to reproduce it with no trouble and so was a coworker. I will write up a bug report and submit it. Once that is done I will be closing the case. The best workaround is the one you found of clicking the Print Layout icon. The only other one I found is to remove the data source, which is not a practical option with a report.

Comment: Same issue here. Do MS actually ever bother testing products before throwing them out of the door? "Print Report" is not exactly an obscure requirement.